Одиночные деепричастия
Возник вопрос касательно обособления одиночных деепричастий. Приведу несколько примеров из текста, который попался (перефразировано, но суть такая же):

Он медленно приближался к ней, хромая и улыбаясь.

Если было бы одно деепричастие, то запятая не нужна ("он медленно приближался к ней хромая (каким образом?)". А что, если деепричастия два?

Он медленно приближался к ней, чуть хромая и криво улыбаясь.

Похожий пример, но появились зависимые слова. Насколько понимаю, в данном случае обособлять нужно, но все еще не уверена. И изменится ли что-то в пунктуации, если предложения будут такими:
Он медленно приближался к ней, чуть хромая и улыбаясь.
Или даже: "Он медленно приближался к ней, чуть хромая".
Влияют ли на что-то слова вроде "чуть"/"слегка"?
3. Он замер, раскрыв рот.
Обычно при таком расположении деепричастия действие совершается после основного. Насколько это предложение логически правильное?
С одной стороны, ничего сложного. Но чем больше изучаю правила, тем сильнее/чаще не покидает ощущение, что везде есть какой-то подвох. Поэтому решила, что лучше бы уточнить. Заранее спасибо.

ТЕОРИЯ

В этой теме более значимым является грамматический, структурный и интонационный анализ, чем какие-либо правила.

Деепричастие не обособляется, если является обстоятельством образа действия. По грамматике нормальная позиция обстоятельства  образа действия (обычно наречия)  — это расположение непосредственно после сказуемого: бежать бЫстро.

Если обособленное обстоятельство выражено одиночным деепричастием или деепричастным оборотом, то чаще это деепричастие несов.вида. Чаще, но не обязательно. Также оборот должен быть нераспространенным. В редких случаях обстоятельством могут быть два деепричастия при наличии союза И.

Откуда такие требования? Дело в том, что деепричастная конструкция должна вписаться в структуру предложения, заняв позицию обстоятельства, при этом ударение падает на деепричастие, но не падает на глагол (одно ударение). Именно тогда деепричастие становится смысловым центром высказывания.  При обособлении у нас два ударения — на сказуемом и на деепричастии.


Следуя этой информации, можно без особого труда решать задачи по этой теме.
ПРАКТИКА
(1) Он медленно приближался к ней, хромая и улыбаясь.
(2) Он медленно приближался к ней, чуть хромая и криво улыбаясь.
(3) Он медленно приближался к ней, чуть хромая и улыбаясь.
(4) Он медленно приближался к ней, чуть хромая.
(5) Он замер, раскрыв рот.

Без контекста я бы обособила все обороты (два ударения).

Что может дать контекст? В сложном предложении меняется расстановка ударений, так что ударение переходит с глагола на деепричастие (тогда ставится одно ударение).


Он медленно приближался к ней чуть хромАя — видимо, полученное ранение давало о себе знАть.
Он медленно приближался к ней чуть хромая и улыбАясь, и она тоже улыбнулась ему в отвЕт.
Он замер раскрыв рОт, и сердце его забИлось.
Пример из Розенталя, пункт 5
Но: В ту же минуту старая женщина… вошла припевая и подплясывая (П.)

Поверим примеры из Розенталя:

В этом случаях  у нас интонация простого предложения, причем ударение уходит в конец предложения (оборот является смысловым центром).
Она сидела /чуть откинув гОлову (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; Жили Артамоновы / ни с кем не знакомясь (М. Г.) — важно, что жили без всяких знакомств; Это упражнение делают / стоя на вытянутых носкАх — смысл сообщения в том, каким образом делают упражнение; *Старик шёл / прихрамывая на правую нОгу;  И т.д.
Кстати, контекст в этих примерах тоже желательно уточнить.

А в этом примере оборот  в начале предложения, но ударение тоже только на деепричастии:

Не унижАя себя говорю, а говорю с болью в сЕрдце (М. Г.);

Спасибо за разъяснение!
